# Extending equivalence relation

Tags: relations

An equivalence relation on $\{-8,\dots,8\}$ is given by explicitly writing down the equivalence classes:
\begin{align}
[0]&=\{0\} \\
[1]&=\{1,-1\} \\
[2]&=\{2,-2,3,-3,5,-5,7,-7\} \\
[4]&=\{4,-4\} \\
[6]&=\{6,-6,8,-8\}
\end{align}
Is there a relation R on $\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $R=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} | a,b \text{ satisfy } (*)\}$, which gives restricted to $\{-8,...,8\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ exactly the above equivalence classes?
Of course, I can define R by giving the elements explicitly. Im searching for a condition $(*)$ on the integers, which divides them in equivalence classes (compatible with the above ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Look at the number of divisors of each of the numbers.